# Leave the game to which I was invited

Tags: google-play-games

I have problem with dealing with invitations. 
Scenario:
1. Friend invites me to his game
2. I join to the game via push notification
3. onSignInSucceeded() in MenuActivity runs my main game activity

```
@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {
    Games.Invitations.registerInvitationListener(getApiClient(), this);


    if (getInvitationId() != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FindRoomActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(BundleConstants.FRIEND_GAME_CLIENT, true);
        intent.putExtra(BundleConstants.INVITATION_ID, getInvitationId());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

4. Friend leaves the game before it ends, on my screen popup shows up and after confirmation I'm back in my Menuactivity, and again runs code form onSignInSucceeded and once again getInvitationId() returns invitation to the same (canceled) game.

I was trying to run declineRoomInvitation or dismissRoomInvitation before I leave that canceled game, but nothing helps.

Comment: How exactly "leaving" the game. Are you just ending the activity or something?

Comment: @Clay - I use Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(getApiClient(), this, mRoom.getRoomId());

Comment: He leaves game 3 seconds after start ;-)

Comment: See this is weird for realtime multiplayer. I have made a turnbased multiplayer and it's easy to detect when some one leaves a match becuase you get a call to `onTurnBasedMatchReceived`. I'm looking for something similar for realtime multiplayer...

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I have an idea. I don't see why this wouldn't work.

When you call `Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(getApiClient(), this, mRoom.getRoomId());`, you are inputting a `RoomUpdateListener` which has listeners: `onJoinedRoom`, `onLeftRoom`, `onRoomCreated` and `onRoomConnected`.

So this is what you do, when a player leaves a game, his/her `onLeftRoom` will be called, when it is called, send a message to the other player using `Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.sendReliableMessage`, then when the other player receives this message, he/she will know that the player left the game so you can make the invitation for that game `null` so when `signInSucceeded` gets called again, it won't try to accept an invitation to a canceled game.

I think this is the best way to implement it. Hope this has been of help :)

Comment: There is method onPeerLeft(Room room, List<String> strings) so there is no need to send msg when someone left, onPeerLeft would notify you, but you answer helped, after start new activity I'll set invitation to null and see what will happen :)